# Setting onItemClickListener in a Main Activity that extends ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a following problem. I build a listView that then uses custom laytout item_event which displays certain data. This all works. Now I want to make the app allow me to move to new activity everytime I click on one of the elements in the listView. My MainMenu extends ListActivity so I can use setListAdapter. How can I now use the setOnItemClickListener? I tried to create ListView object and then refer to it, but I cannot access it due to its             android:id="@android:id/list"/>. How to do it?

```
package com.mysampleapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListActivity;


import com.userpreferencesom.AmazonClientManager;
import com.userpreferencesom.DynamoDBManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MainMenu extends ListActivity {

    //ListView eventsList;
    Button newEvent;
    Event event= new Event();
    //ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList();


    public static AmazonClientManager clientManager = null;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = null;
    private ArrayList<String> labels = null; // list of names of events manly for test)
    private ArrayList<Event> items = null;  //stores events

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        clientManager = new AmazonClientManager(this); //CIPEK
        new GetEventList().execute(); //calling GetEventList from included class below

        newEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_event_button);

        newEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, EventCreationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    private void setupActivity() {
        Log.v("MOJEMOJEMOJE", event.getName());
    }

    private class GetEvent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            event = DynamoDBManager.getEvent("");  //in bracket ID number
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            setupActivity();
        }
    }


    private class GetEventList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... inputs) {

            labels = new ArrayList<String>();

            items = DynamoDBManager.getEventList();

            for (Event up : items) {
                labels.add(up.getName());
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Log.v("Events:", labels.toString());
            updateDisplay();

        }
    }

    public void updateDisplay(){
        //Using Event Adapter to display data
        EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, R.layout.item_event, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { //HERE IT CANNOT BUILD
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, EventViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance,
John

Here is the error log:

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\trial\cos1\HangApp-0.5\app\src\main\java\com\mysampleapp\MainMenu.java
Error:(110, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setOnItemClickListener(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Might be helpful if you include an error you 're getting

Comment: Is there any error? Bcoz ur setOnItemCliclListener looks fine. Please post the error message also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Override` `onListItemClick` for handle event when you click in each item of your `ListView`

```
public class MainMenu extends ListActivity
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Toast.makeText(this, "click at " + position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```